# why can water heated to a certain temperature in microwave explode when removing cup , bowl etc to room temperature air?

Tags: gas-laws, energy, heat

Studied a lot about $\mathrm{pH}$ , molecule dipoles properties $\ce{H2O}$. never saw anything along lines of energy storage, except ice contains heat energy , ionization of water always happens. boiling is vapor pressure of water overcoming that atmospheric pressure , why can not do it (boil) at high altitudes. Can you get the water hot though at a  high altitude?  Question about microwave exploding was main question I wish answered ,tks. Water buoy Doug.

Comment: Try to clean and organize your thoughts more while writing a question. This is rather a mess. If it was like four time longer, it would not be readable.

Comment: "Opposite" and related https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaze_(ice)

Answer (score 2):

Water in a microwave oven can get easily overheated above boiling point and then by a random trigger starts boiling violently.

With increasing altitude and decreasing pressure, boiling point of water gets lower. If low enough, cooking of various food becomes impossible, unless pressurized cookware is used.

If a vacuum pump decreases air pressure enough, water boils even at room temperature. See also [Wikipedia: Armstrong limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit) for atmospheric biological limitations:

> The Armstrong limit or Armstrong's line is a measure of altitude above which atmospheric pressure is sufficiently low that water boils at the normal temperature of the human body. Exposure to pressure below this limit results in a rapid loss of consciousness, followed by a series of changes to cardiovascular and neurological functions, and eventually death, unless pressure is restored within 60–90 seconds.On Earth, the limit is around 18–19 km (11–12 mi; 59,000–62,000 ft) above sea level, above which atmospheric air pressure drops below 0.0618 atm (6.3 kPa, 47 mmHg, or about 1 psi). The U.S. Standard Atmospheric model sets the Armstrong pressure at an altitude of 63,000 feet (19,202 m).